# How to simplify this SQL query to select specific string patterns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below

Table T

```
V
__
a
ab
abc
abcd
x
xy
xyz
xyzw
```

I have to get output as

```
abcd
xyzw
```

I have written query as below
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13c56/10

```
with x as 
(select t1.v v1, t2.v v2 
   from t t1, t t2 
  where t1.v not like t2.v||'%')
select distinct v1 
  from x x1
 where not exists
       (select 1 
          from x x2 
         where x2.v2 like x1.v1 ||'%'
           and x2.v2 <> x1.v1)
```

Is there a better way to write this query ? Please share the query.

Comment: What is the exact logic you want to implement?

Comment: When there is access paths like a/b/c, a/b/c/d, x/y, x/y/z. I need to pick distinct longest access paths - a/b/c/d and x/y/z

Comment: Yes, there is a better way to write the query.

Comment: Please share your idea

Comment: Can you have `abcdxyz`?  Does the order matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an outer join to find *longer* similar sequences, then filter out the matches leaving you with only the longest sequences:

```
select v from
(select t1.v, t2.v v2 
   from t t1
   left join t t2 on t2.v like t1.v || '_%') x
where v2 is null
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13c56/20).

Note the use of `_` (meaning exactly one character) in the `like` to require at least 1 more character in the matching row.

Given your dupe-free example data and this logic, `distinct` is not needed. However if you have duplicate longest sequences and you want to dedupe those, add `distinct`.